# Tag too similar is misspelling?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation-process

On my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925853/kubernetes-ingress-whitelist-ip-for-path), I tried to add the tag [ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ingress), but it wouldn't let me, saying it was too similar to the existing tag [ingres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ingres).  Is this a misspelling, and should I be allowed to create the [ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ingress) tag?

Comment: Seems like you're looking for [tag:kubernetes-ingress]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a misspelling,

No, it's not a misspelling. [Ingres](https://www.actian.com/data-management/actian-x-hybrid-rdbms/) is a widely used relational database.

> and should I be allowed to create the ingress tag?

Per Rob's comment, there's already a tag ([kubernetes-ingress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kubernetes-ingress)) for the topic you're asking about. On that grounds, we probably don't need an 'ingress' tag.